# How to avoid very large files

Tags: go

Hello everyone I ask for your help since I have a question in golang using forms. Suppose I have this field in an html form:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
```

And I want to receive the file in golang, which I do with the following code:

```
func index(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := r.ParseMultipartForm(0)

    if err != nil {
      log.Print("Error")
    }

    file, _, _ := r.FormFile("file")

    log.Print(file)
}
```

So far so good, and I think I really have the file. But now my question is, how can I see the weight of the file before having it saved? I mean, if I understand correctly the [go documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request.ParseMultipartForm) says:

> The whole request body is parsed and up to a total of maxMemory bytes
> of its file parts are stored in memory, with the remainder stored on
> disk in temporary files.

What I understand (please tell me if I'm wrong) is that the file is saved on the server, I mean on the computer, the problem is, if I have a very limited space on my computer, a very large file could not fill my computer space temporarily and crash the server?

How can I avoid this problem? How can I see the size of the file without actually having the file? Or, how can I limit the size of the file that is uploaded to the server without having the file?

I hope I have made myself understood, and I repeat, if I have misunderstood something please tell me. Thanks in advance :D.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MaxBytesReader and avoid accepting larger files.

```
r.Body = http.MaxBytesReader(w, r.Body, MaxAllowedSize)
err := r.ParseMultipartForm(MaxAllowedSize)
if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Can not handle files bigger than %dmb, failed with %s", MaxAllowedSize/(1024*1024), err)
        return
}
```

[example handler](https://github.com/malisetti/ummage/blob/master/um/app.go#L55)

Comment: If the goal is protection this is the superior answer because the header value is convention and can be manipulated.